# Doubt in Newton’s 3rd law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If I push a body with f =5N.The body also exerts a force of 5N on me(Action reaction pair).If the resultant is zero , how does the body move at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire system including you & the object to which you're applying force & the resultant force of this system is zero(however if we neglect the gravitational force acting on you & the object as well). But the force on the object is effective if it is not too massive & it'll obviously change the momentum of the object. You're massive enough that this 5N force will not affect you. You may imagine to strike a rigid wall by your fist. You're applying force to the wall but this is not enough to break the wall, resultant force of the system (your fist & the wall) is zero, but you & the wall both experience the force with zero effectiveness.

Comment: If v = 0, then p I also 0.